# C++ unordered set out of memory

Tags: c++, algorithm, memory-management, for-loop

This program goes through every combination of 4 numbers from 1 - 400 and sees how many unique numbers can be made from the product.
I believe the `unordered_set` used to hold the already checked numbers is getting too large and thus it quits;  task manager tells me it's at 1.5 GB.

Is there any way I can make this code run? I think maybe splitting up the set or somehow finding a more efficient formula.

Note: based on the comments, I would like to say again I am not storing all 25 billion numbers. I'm only storing ~100,000,000 numbers. The question has a `RANGE` of 400, but I'm looking for a comprehensive solution that can handle 500, or even 1000 without the memory problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

const int RANGE = 400;

int main(){

    unordered_set<long long> nums;

    for(long long a=1; a<=RANGE; a++)
    {
        for(long long b=a; b<=RANGE; b++)
        {
            for(long long c=b; c<=RANGE; c++)
            {
                for(long long d=c; d<=RANGE; d++)
                {
                    unordered_set<long long>::const_iterator got = nums.find(a*b*c*d);
                    if (got == nums.end())
                    {
                        nums.insert(a*b*c*d);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    cout << nums.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 400^4 is 25,600,000,000 - 25 billion ints will take quite a bit of memory to store, even when you eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: You're basically trying to find all numbers minus the primes from 1 to 400*400*400*400. That's going to approach 25,600,000,000 numbers. Not going to fit in memory no matter what you do.

Comment: @MarkRansom That is not correct, there are millions of numbers that are composite but I will not include, like 31^5.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I am not storing all 25 billion, only those that can be factored into 4 integers within 1 through 100.

Comment: Actually, as a bitset (one bit per entry), it would fit in about 3GB of memory. Of course, that's not going to happen in a 32-bit appliction or a machine with much less than 4GB of RAM. And you probably need the code compiled for 64-bit, just to allocate more than 2GB as one contiguous chunk of memory.

Comment: BTW your test is superfluous, it is built into `std::unordered_set::insert`.

Comment: I'm not sure I accept your estimate of millions, but it doesn't matter. Millions out of billions is just a rounding error. And @MatsPetersson you should make that an answer.

Comment: I just compiled this code on my machine, and it requires around 3.5-4GB of ram to complete (using g++ and glibc on Linux, other OS's, compilers and libraries may differ)

Comment: Can anybody solve this in `o(RANGE^4)` time? I would find that really interesting. Let alone `o(n)` time where `n` is the output number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works by doing every unique permutation of four numbers between 1 and 400, multiplying them, and storing the results, and then counting them.  At a *minimum*, this would take 400*400*400*400bits ~3GB, which is apperently more than your hardware/compiler/OS can handle.  (Probably the compiler, which is easy to fix)

So what if we try to solve the program one step at a time?  Can we count how many sets of these numbers have products between 1000 and 2000?

```
for(a=1; a<400; ++a)
{
    bmin = max(1000/a/400/400, a); //a*b*400*400 is at least 1000
    bmax = min(2000/a, 400);       //a*b*1*1 is at most 2000
    for(b=bmin; b<=bmax; b++)
    {
        cmin = max(1000/a/b/400, b);  //a*b*c*400 is at least 1000
        cmax = min(2000/a/b, 400);    //a*b*c*1 is at most 2000
        for(c=cmin; c<=cmax; c++)
        {
            dmin = max(1000/a/b/c, c);   //a*b*c*d is at least 1000
            dmax = min(2000/a/b/c, 400); //a*b*c*d is at most 2000
            for(d=dmin; d<=dmax; d++) //this will usually be zero, one, or two numbers
            {
                res = a*b*c*d;
                if (res>=1000 && res<2000) //a rare few WILL be outside this range
                    YES
```

We can simply count how many products between 0-1000 are accessible, then 1000-2000, then 2000-3000, etc, up to 400*400*400*400.  This is a *significantly* slower algorithm, but since it takes very little memory, the hope is that the increased cache coherence will make up for some of the difference.

In fact, speaking of very little memory, since the target numbers in each batch are always in a sequential range of 1000, then you can use a `bool nums[1000] = {}` instead of an `unordered_set`, which should give a *significant* performance boost.

My full code is here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc1739e972cb40f0, and I have confirmed my code has the same results as yours.  After fixing several bugs, your algorithm still vastly outperforms mine for small `RANGE` with MSVC2013. (For anyone else testing this with MSVC, be sure to test with the debugger NOT attached, it makes a HUGE difference in the timing of the original code)

```
origional(   4) found          25 in      0s
     duck(   4) found          25 in      0s
origional(   6) found          75 in      0s
     duck(   6) found          75 in      0s
origional(   9) found         225 in      0s
     duck(   9) found         225 in      0s
origional(  13) found         770 in      0s
     duck(  13) found         770 in      0s
origional(  17) found        1626 in  0.001s
     duck(  17) found        1626 in      0s
origional(  25) found        5135 in  0.004s
     duck(  25) found        5135 in  0.002s
origional(  35) found       14345 in  0.011s
     duck(  35) found       14345 in  0.015s
origional(  50) found       49076 in  0.042s
     duck(  50) found       49075 in  0.076s
origional(  71) found      168909 in  0.178s
     duck(  71) found      168909 in  0.738s
origional( 100) found      520841 in  0.839s
     duck( 100) found      520840 in  7.206s
origional( 141) found     1889918 in  5.072s
     duck( 141) found     1889918 in 76.028s
```

When I study the issue, what finally occurred to me is that my algorithm requires a large number of 64bit divisions, which seems to be slow even in 64bit operating systems.

Comment: This seems like it'll work, but what's the point of `bmin` `bmax` `cmin`  `cmax` `dmin` `dmax`? They seem unnecessary, as you could "direct" the program to the correct range array? I'm not sure how this would be done though.

Comment: @qwr: If you're aiming for the range 1000-2000, and `a=20` and `b=30`, then `cmax=2000/20/30=3`. That means `c` is only tested for values 1, 2, and 3, instead of all the way up to 400. Anything above 3 would be over the max. Similarly, if `a=1` and `b=1` and `c=3` then `dmin=1000/1/1/3=333`, which means you only have to test `d` from 333-400. Anything smaller won't reach the minimum. It's possible that `bmin`, `bmax`, or others are reduntant, but it's not immediately obvious to me which are. I know that removing `dmin`, or `dmax` makes the program MUCH MUCH slower.

Comment: "At a minimum, this would take 400*400*400*400bits" That's not true, it takes *number of distinct products \* size of an integer* space.

Comment: @NiklasB. as that number is even bigger, my statement stands :D

Comment: Well not exactly, `86e6 * 8` (assuming 8-byte ints) is smaller than `400^4 / 8`. It becomes more relevant for even larger ranges than 400. It's a minor nitpick though because it's not sensible to keep all the stuff in memory anyway

Comment: @NiklasB.: it also occurs to me that the minimum (with a range of 400) is a mere 360M, but that would require a specialized data structure with a perfect hash, packing into 35bit integers. :D

Comment: Technically if you went into fractions of a bit (yes, it is possible), then you could go even lower.

Comment: There's a discrepancy for `50` and `100`? And I'm sure there's a way around using multiple divisions. I'll investigate further tomorrow.

Comment: Good spot on the 50 and 100!  I'll have to figure that out...  I've done tests with the divisions, it appears that the compiler is smart enough to optimize the number of divisions shockingly well, the problem is simply that you need at least two divisions per inner loop.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to compile the code with a 64-bit compiler to allow allocating of more than around 2GB of memory. You will also need at least 4GB of RAM on the machine you are running this on, or at best it will take almost forever to finish.

A "bitset", using a single bit per entry will take up about 3GB of memory.

Using the code as it stands, it will use around 4GB of memory on a Linux machine with 64-bit g++ compiler, and it takes around 220 seconds to complete, giving the answer:

```
86102802
1152921504606846975
```

According to /usr/bin/time -v:

```
Command being timed: "./a.out"
User time (seconds): 219.15
System time (seconds): 2.01
Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 3:42.53
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4069336
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 679924
Voluntary context switches: 1
Involuntary context switches: 23250
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

Comment: This is what I considered, but is there a solution for 1-500? or 1-1000? Is there a way to not have all the data in memory at once?

Comment: There are probably ways, but it gets a bit complicated when you start dealing with large files too, and it typically gets very slow too (hard disk has access times in the millisecond range, even slow memory is in the 100ns range. So hard disk is approx 1000 times slower). Given that it takes a fair amount of time anyway, it's probably unlikely to work well at 1000 times slower - even if it's only 1000 times slower once in a while, it's going to have a fair impact. Imagine flying at 1000 mph, and then getting out walking for a mile at a time, once every 15 minutes...

Comment: @qwr I'm pretty sure there's a better algorithm than the brute-force approach. You should however open a new question for that, since is has nothing to do with the original question here.

Comment: Range of 500, on my machine, otherwise same as above takes up about 8GB of RAM. Which isn't increadibly much, but at 1000^4 we're talking much larger amounts, so that's probably unfeasible. As Niklas says, you may want to use a different method for solving the problem - I'm not always that clever with algo's, so not sure if there's another solution easily available.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: I think it's possible to solve this question for arbitrary ranges of the results, (1000 < A*B*C*D <= 2000), and if you can do _that_ efficiently, then you can simply iterate over ranges of target results, which would use O(1) memory (and small at that), bypassing the swapping concerns.

Comment: @MooingDuck That sounds feasible. Can you post more detail as an answer?

Comment: @MatsPetersson wait, why does your output have two lines?

Comment: Because I copied and pasted the code that was in the code-sample posted originally - which also outputs the `max_size` as the second item.